# BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc0000017 error after random shutdown

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, bootable-media, out-of-memory

My computer was running perfectly, as normal, then shutdown and started going into a bootloop, getting to the first windows 10 loading step, then restarting. When I forced it to shutdown, and started it back up, I got the BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc0000017 error message.

I tried to boot into the USB media that I had originally installed the OS from, to try and run a repair, but it just says "out of memory, press any key to continue" which results in the BlInitializeLibrary error again.

Its an ASUS mobo, windows 10... Not sure what else I'll need. Every answer I've found has said the SSD is corrupted which sucks but would be fine if I could boot from USB and reinstall on the HDD, but I can't even get that to work.

Help please!

Edit: okay I've actually managed to get it to boot by unplugging one of the drives, though I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: See this>>>>https://betanews.com/2016/01/06/how-to-fix-error-0xc0000017-when-installing-windows-10/